# SQL Order of processing

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all, except

Consider I have a query like

```
select * from A
Except 
select * from B 
union all
select * from B 
except
select * from A
```

Query is processed like

```
select * 
from 
(
select * from A
Except 
select * from B 
) a
union all
(
select * from B
Except 
select * from A 
) b
```

How is the order of processing defined in sql. Will it process like this at any case

```
select * from A
Except 
select * from
(
select * from B 
union all
select * from B 
) a
except
select * from A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION` and `EXCEPT` have **equal precedence** but will bind from left to right, meaning they are evaluated in "left to right" order, as they are processed.

From @SeanLange's URL (TL;DR), worth taking note of:

> If **EXCEPT** or **INTERSECT** is used together with other operators in an
> expression, it is evaluated in the context of the following
> precedence:
>
> - Expressions in parentheses
> - The INTERSECT operator
> - **EXCEPT** and **UNION** evaluated from left to right based on their position in the
>   expression

Answer (score 5):

EXCEPT and UNION are processed "left to right". Meaning that without any parenthesis to make the determination they will process in the order they appear in the sql.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx